# Find area of 2d polygon formed by rect and line

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, area, rectangles

I'm making game in Unity. There's a rectangle intersected by a straight line. I need to find which part of rect is bigger and how much. Do anyone knows algorithm how to do this?
[image: Example]

Rect and lines are set with points (4 for rect and 2 for lines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit equation of the line is

```
S(x,y) = (x - x0) (y1 - y0) - (y - y0) (x1 - x0) = 0
```

When you plug the coordinates of a corner, the sign of `S(x, y)` tells you on what side of the line you are. And better, if you evaluate `Sa` and `Sb` at two corners and they have different signs, the intersection is at a fraction `Sa / (Sa - Sb)` along the side `ab`.

Now, process all four edges in turn in clockwise order. For every edge, keep the starting corner if positive and keep the intersection if any. In the end, you'll get 0 to 5 points defining the convex polygon which is in the positive domain.

[image]

The area is found by the [shoelace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Simple_polygons) formula.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Determine if the shaded area is purely a triangle, if so, calculate the area of that triangle (a * b) / 2 , this would solve the right hand diagram.

For the left hand diagram, treat the area as a triangle and a rectangle.  Compute the shaded area by adding together the triangles area and the rectangles area.

HTH